# Android handler to wake thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have a a separate thread that is a looping thread that declares a handler, as shown below:

```
class LooperThread extends Thread{
    Handler h = null;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        Looper.prepare();
        h = new MyHandler();
        Looper.loop();
    }
 }
```

And I also have a seperate thread that is sleeping.  The code for myHandler synchronizes on the same lock that my other thread is waiting on and then calls Notify after doing some work.  However, the original thread waits and the message that is sent from the separate service to the handler is not being reached by the handler.  I am certain that the message is being sent from the service.  I understand that a Handler creates a message queue for the thread it was built on however, if the handler is built on a separate looping thread wouldn't this thread not sleep if the original thread is?  I have tried handlerThread and a few other alternatives but to no avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more data if you want help (is this still a problem or have you figured it out?) Maybe you can explain more about how the messages, threads and handlers are supposed to work.